# How do I detect if the user's font (DPI)?

Tags: dpi

I'm trying to find out what DPI setting my application is running on.

I have tried.

```
Using g As Graphics = MyBase.CreateGraphics()
        dpiX = g.DpiX
        dpiY = g.DpiY
End Using

TextBox1.Text = dpiX.ToString()
TextBox2.Text = dpiy.ToString()
```

And I have tried to use

```
 Dim searcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher( _
                "root\CIMV2", _
                "SELECT * FROM Win32_DisplayConfiguration") 

            For Each queryObj As ManagementObject in searcher.Get()
            TextBox3.Text = string.Format("LogPixels: {0}", queryObj("LogPixels"))
```

Both displays 96 DPI. On my normal computer and also on my virtual with DPI set to 150%.

How do I find the correct DPI of the current screen?

//Linus

Answer (score 0):

I found what the problem is.

I didn't have a application manifest file that hade the dpiaware set.

```
<asmv3:application xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <asmv3:windowsSettings
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">
        <dpiAware>True/PM</dpiAware>
    </asmv3:windowsSettings>
</asmv3:application>
```

With this it's working as expected.